# JUnit test case not working

Tags: java, string, junit4

I'm trying to test this method:

```
public static String trimExtraSpace(String str) {
    str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    return str;
}
```

Junit test case that I have:

```
@Test
public void testTrimExtraSpace() {
    String str = " foo \n   b  a    r ";
    assertEquals("foo \n b a r", Strings.trimExtraSpace(str));      
}
```

**Reuslt:**
[image: Screenshot]

Why this do not want to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String`s are immutable in Java. You have to do something like this:

```
public static String trimExtraSpace(String str) {
    String trimmedStr = str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    return trimmedStr;
}
```

You also probably have to change the regexp used in `replaceAll` (I can't test):

```
String trimmedStr = str.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess from the API documentation trim() method returns a String instance, you need to catch that instance and do operation on it and then return the (returned) instance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use regular expression. In this case:

```
urString = yourString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Have fun